# (Beginner) Reset adapter? (Data set does not change)

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter, baseadapter

I am trying to recreate the same listview activity once an option has been clicked, only it isn't working. I have tried `SubjectSelectorActivity.this.recreate();` and `startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));` but that doesn't reset the onclick result. What is a line of code that I can use for recreating and resetting the onclick result in my Activity/Adapter? I would also like to recreate it so that I can animate the screen sliding to the left and showing the new recreated activity, so if that could be worked into the code as well that would be fantastic. Also, if you see anything wrong with my code or there is an easier way of doing something (probably is because I am a beginner) please let me know :)

**Code**:

```
package com.example.adend.timetable.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import com.example.adend.timetable.R;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.adend.timetable.appwidgets.AbsThemeActivity;
import com.kabouzeid.appthemehelper.ThemeStore;


public class SubjectSelectorActivity extends AbsThemeActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    SubjectAdapter adapter;

    public static int[] subjectIcons ={
            R.drawable.cross,
            R.drawable.tags,
            R.drawable.film,
            R.drawable.book,
            R.drawable.food,
            R.drawable.earth,
            R.drawable.heart_pulse,
            R.drawable.run,
            R.drawable.history,
            R.drawable.indo,
            R.drawable.jap,
            R.drawable.law,
            R.drawable.calculator,
            R.drawable.film,
            R.drawable.library_music,
            R.drawable.earth,
            R.drawable.bike,
            R.drawable.hammer,
            R.drawable.run,
            R.drawable.phsy,
            R.drawable.currency_usd,
            R.drawable.microscope,
            R.drawable.drawing_box,
            R.drawable.settings,
            R.drawable.tshirt_crew,
            R.drawable.drawing_box,
            R.drawable.settings,
    };

    public static String[] subjects = {
            "Christian ED",
            "Coding and Informatics",
            "Drama",
            "English",
            "Food Studies",
            "Geography",
            "Health",
            "Health/PE",
            "History",
            "Indonesian",
            "Japanese",
            "Law and Economics",
            "Mathematics",
            "Media Arts",
            "Music",
            "Our World",
            "Outdoor Education",
            "PDT – Materials",
            "Phys ED",
            "Psychology",
            "Running a Small Business",
            "Science",
            "Studio Arts",
            "Systems Engineering",
            "Textiles",
            "Visual Communication Design",
            "Custom",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_selector);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Button next = (findViewById(R.id.next));
        Button cancel = (findViewById(R.id.cancel));
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ThemeStore.primaryColor(this));
        setStatusbarColor(ThemeStore.primaryColor(this));
        next.setTextColor(ThemeStore.primaryColor(this));

        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        context = this;

        lv = findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new SubjectAdapter(this, subjects, subjectIcons);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public int getCounter() {
        SharedPreferences getnotch = context.getSharedPreferences("counter", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int defaultValue = 0;
        int notch = getnotch.getInt("counter", defaultValue);
        return notch;
    }

    private String getPass() {
        SharedPreferences pass = context.getSharedPreferences("pass", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String defaultValue = null;
        String passi = pass.getString("pass", defaultValue);
        return passi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String subposition = getPass();

        if (getPass() != null) {

            SharedPreferences counter = getSharedPreferences("counter", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor countereditor = counter.edit();

            if (getCounter() == 0) {

                SharedPreferences sharedMonP1 = getSharedPreferences("MonP1", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor monp1editor = sharedMonP1.edit();
                monp1editor.putString("MonP1", subposition);
                monp1editor.commit();

                countereditor.putInt("counter", getCounter() + 1);
                countereditor.commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));

                // restart activity for a new onclick result - tried "startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));"
                // but it keeps the same onclick result and sets all of the SharedPreferences as the same string.
                // As it restarts, animation slide to left

            }

            if (getCounter() == 1) {
                SharedPreferences sharedMonP2 = getSharedPreferences("MonP2", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor monp2editor = sharedMonP2.edit();
                monp2editor.putString("MonP2", subposition);
                monp2editor.commit();

                countereditor.putInt("counter", getCounter() + 1);
                countereditor.commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));

                // restart activity for a new onclick result - tried "startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));"
                // but it keeps the same onclick result and sets all of the SharedPreferences as the same string.
                // As it restarts, animation slide to left
            }

            if (getCounter() == 2) {
                SharedPreferences sharedMonP3 = getSharedPreferences("MonP3", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor monp3editor = sharedMonP3.edit();
                monp3editor.putString("MonP3", subposition);
                monp3editor.commit();

                countereditor.putInt("counter", getCounter() + 1);
                countereditor.commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));

                // restart activity for a new onclick result - tried "startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, SubjectSelectorActivity.class));"
                // but it keeps the same onclick result and sets all of the SharedPreferences as the same string.
                // As it restarts, animation slide to left
            }

            if (getCounter() == 3) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SubjectSelectorActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }
    }

    public class SubjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] result;
        int[] imageId;
        Context context;

        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;


        public SubjectAdapter(SubjectSelectorActivity subjectSelector, String[] subjects, int[] subjectIcons) {
            result = subjects;
            context = subjectSelector;
            imageId = subjectIcons;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return result.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView tv1;
            ImageView img;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (getCounter() == 3){
                SharedPreferences counter = getSharedPreferences("counter", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor countereditor = counter.edit();
                countereditor.putInt("counter", 0);
                countereditor.commit();
            }

            Holder holder = new Holder();
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subject, null);
            holder.tv1 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtext);
            holder.img = rowView.findViewById(R.id.subimg);
            holder.tv1.setText(result[position]);
            holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String sub = result[position];

                    SharedPreferences passs = getSharedPreferences("pass", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor passe = passs.edit();
                    passe.putString("pass", sub);
                    passe.commit();

                }

            });

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why extend AbsThemeActivity? Listview is depricated, use recyclerview instead. Perhaps use OnitemClickListener for listviews

Comment: ListView is not yet deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Whenever the data fed to the adapter is changed and you want to reset your listView to create the views again.

If you want to redraw all the items in a listView, use

```
 lv.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work - where about's should I be putting this? I tried in both onclicks and the getView method.

Comment: This works only when you change or update the data fed to the adapter.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try the other option now.

Comment: I'm not trying to update the items, I am just trying to restart the activity and reset the onclick result (I think?). The data doesn't change